# Python program Query

Tags: python, numbers

This is a question from John Guttag's book *Introduction to Computation and Programming Using Python*

> Write a program that prints out the greatest odd number out of three numbers and an alternate error message if none of the numbers are odd.

This is my program. Is it correct? Does it cover all possibilities? I tried thinking it this way - exhaust all possibilities for the 3 statements - x is the largest, y is the largest and z is the largest - one by one. Is it the correct approach? Anyway, this is my program.

```
if ((x>y and x>z) or (x>y and x<z and z%2==0) or (x>z and x<y and 
 y%2==0) or (x<z and x<y and y%2==0 and z%2==0)) and x%2!=0:
    print(x)
elif (y>z and y%2!=0) or (y<z and z%2==0)
    print(y)
elif z%2!=0:
    print(z)
else:
    print('None of the numbers are odd')
```

Comment: what if 2 number are  __odd__ and 1 is __even__ ?  
should we find max for only odd nos. or we can consider the even one also?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. I corrected the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It's almost correct**

You are very close but you've forgotten a condition for when `x` is not printed and `y` and `z` are both even. Try the example of `(4,2,6)` for `(x,y,z)`. Your exhaustive reasoning makes sense, but it is hard to program like this. I want to walk through your current logic then show how your code can be simplified, but your approach is clear using only if-else and indentation.

**Your logic**

In your logic you check all possibilities where you would ever print `x` which is if any following are true so long as `x` is odd:

1. `x` is the largest of `x`, `y`, and `z`
2. `x` is bigger than `y` when `z` is even
3. `x` is bigger than `z` when `y` is even
4. `y` and `z` are even

Then in the first `elif` you test whether to print `y` and make the correct decision to no longer check `x` at all since the first `if` handled all the cases where you would want to print `x`.
This is where your mistake is, however, since you should keep the same logical structure as your `if` statement for `x`:

```
elif ((y>z) or (y<z and z%2==0)) and y%2!=0:
```

You do the same for `z` in the last `elif` and then use `else` if all are even.

**Simplifying your logic**

We can simplify the first `if` statement where you check for `x`. One small note is that it is better to check that `x` is odd before doing all the `or` checks, since if `x` is even the computer doesn't have to look at all the `or` logic (short-circuiting):

```
if x%2 != 0 and ((x>y and x>z) or (x>y and x<z and z%2==0) or (x>z and x<y and 
 y%2==0) or (x<z and x<y and y%2==0 and z%2==0)):
```

Next the `or` logic can be simplified to:

```
if x%2 != 0 and ((x>=y and x>=z) or (x>=y and z%2==0) or (x>=z and 
 y%2==0) or (y%2==0 and z%2==0)):
```

All the simplifications came from the idea that if `y` or `z` is even we don't need to compare it to `x` since we'd want to print `x` regardless. I've also changed the `>` to `>=` or you would have had errors if some of the variables had the same values.

With the same reasoning we can simplify the first `elif` to:

```
elif ((y>=z) or (z%2==0)) and y%2!=0:
```

**Bonus**

If we know `x`, `y`, and `z` are not negative you can do this little trick. Try to work it out, leave a comment if you have questions or figure out how to make it work with negatives.

```
x = x*(x%2)
y = y*(y%2)
z = z*(z%2)

if x+y+z == 0:
    print('None of the numbers are odd')
elif x >= y and x >= z:
    print(x)
elif y >= x and y >= z:
    print(y)
elif z >= x and z >= y:
    print(z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Three simple steps:

1. Filter the list
2. Check if empty
3. Get max

---

```
filtered_list = filter(lambda x:x%2!=0, [x, y, z])
if filtered_list:
    print max(filtered_list)
else:
    print "No Odd number given"
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. At the point where I am in the book, functions like lambda have not yet been introduced. Only if-else and basic indentation. Thanks anyway, I will try to check out how filter and lambda work.

Comment: You can replace filter with your own function which return the filtered list.

Also if this suffice your query. Kindly tick the answer to close the thread

Answer (score 0):

- This is the **Efficient code** for finding *whether the given number is odd or not*.
- Here I used **'&' (and bitwise operator)** which do **bitwise and** with **one** .

  - let the number 5(00000101)
    when we do 5 & 1 then it will do (00000101) & (00000001) = (00000001).
  - This will happen with all other odd numbers.

---

```
ip = []
ip = map(int,raw_input().split())
odds = filter(lambda x :  x & 1 != 0 , ip)
if len(odds) > 0 :
    print (max(odds))
else :
    print ("None of the numbers are odd")
```